# spliting a line at a parentheses in perl

Tags: string, perl, split

I have this string that I want to split at the opening parentheses.

```
SUBJ/TROPICAL DEPRESSION 26W (TWENTYSIX) WARNING NR 002/
```

In this case I would have two strings which would be

```
SUBJ/TROPICAL DEPRESSION 26W
```

and

```
TWENTYSIX) WARNING NR 002/
```

I have tried to use the split function for this doing

```
$line=" SUBJ/TROPICAL DEPRESSION 26W (TWENTYSIX) WARNING NR 002/"
@namearr = split /\(/, ${line);
```

but I wind up getting an error message.

```
(Might be a runaway multi-line "" string starting on line )
```

How do I tweak the code above so that I can successfully split the line based on the parentheses?

Comment: Misses a `;` after the assignment (`$line="..."` should read `$line="...";`)...

Comment: And `${line)` should probably be `${line}` or just `$line`...

Comment: Just fix the typos identified by @stickybit and your code should produce the expected results.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't result in the error you claim it does. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: A regex match or subtitution is probably more appropriate than `split` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't result in the error you claim it does.

```
$ perl -e'
   $line=" SUBJ/TROPICAL DEPRESSION 26W (TWENTYSIX) WARNING NR 002/"
   @namearr = split /\(/, ${line);
' && echo ok
Array found where operator expected at -e line 3, near "@namearr"
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
syntax error at -e line 3, near "@namearr "
Missing right curly or square bracket at -e line 4, at end of line
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

There are three errors in the code you posted.

1. Missing `;` between the statements.
2. `${line)` is a typo for `${line}`, which should be `$line`. `${line}` works, but this is undocumented and unusual.
3. You didn't limit the scope of your variables. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

```
$ perl -e'
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   my $line = " SUBJ/TROPICAL DEPRESSION 26W (TWENTYSIX) WARNING NR 002/";
   my @namearr = split /\(/, $line;
' && echo ok
ok
```

---

The error you asked about usually happens when you are missing a closing delimiter (quote), or perhaps when your literal has an unescaped delimiter.

```
$ perl -e'
   my $s1 = "foo;
   my $s2 = "bar";
'
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 3, near "my $s2 = "bar"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line "" string starting on line 2)
        (Do you need to predeclare my?)
String found where operator expected at -e line 3, at end of line
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
syntax error at -e line 3, near "my $s2 = "bar"
Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF at -e line 3.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, why not to try something like this instead of **split**?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 1;

my @parts;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    @parts = /(.+)\((.*)\)(.*)/;
}

print Dumper(\@parts) if $debug;

__DATA__
SUBJ/TROPICAL DEPRESSION 26W (TWENTYSIX) WARNING NR 002/
```